# Macro evaluation at compile time?

Tags: c

```
#define CONVERT(val, qin, qout) ((qin > qout) ? (val >> (qin-qout) ) : (val << (qout-qin)))

void f(void)
{
    ...
    y = CONVERT(x, 25, 31);
}
```

Is the above macro going to be evaluated by GCC at compile time? I mean the `(qin > qout)` part. I am trying to have only `y = x << (31-25)` after the compilation is done.

Comment: The compiler should be able to do constant-folding if that's what you wonder. Actually you would probably have `y = x << (6)`. Have you built with optimizations enabled and checked the generated code?

Comment: yes, modern compilers are able to do those kind of optimization pretty easily.

Comment: Note that answer to this question has nothing to do with macro evaluation. You can see what the preprocessor does with the macro by compiling with `-E`. It's the optimizer that will precompute the results of the ternary operator.

Comment: @user3386109 OK, I'll check with `-E`.

Comment: but you probably should use an inline function instead of function

Comment: @phuclv The macro has one single benefit, and that is that it will get optimized even at `-O0`, but to optimize an inline function it needs `-O1`. Sometimes you want to write programs with optimizations completely disabled, such as mission-critical embedded systems. Though of course the macro isn't type safe like a function, so it comes with another form of hazard that one might wish to avoid.

Comment: a problem might be that there is a literal `(1 >> (25 -31))` in the macro expansion.  This might trigger undefined behavior **warnings** (but code will still behave correctly).

Comment: As an aside, you should really put parentheses around the parameters in the macro expansion to avoid problems when the arguments are something other than a primary expression. With your current macro definition, `y = CONVERT(x, 25, 31);` and `y = CONVERT(x, 30 - 5, 31);` would set `y` to different values, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @IanAbbott Good point, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `qin > qout` part will end up as an *integer constant expression* in this case, which the compiler can optimize into `1` or `0` in theory.

In practice, it doesn't even do that. Looking at how real compilers actually treats your example, gcc and clang at `-O0` (optimizations off) only generates the code for the left shift, omitting the conditional check and branch of `?:`, as well as the second operand which is never true.

The machine code ends up boiling down to the equivalent of `y = x << 6;`, completely branch free.